# Undo changes in code (whole project) to a specific commit but Keep all the "git logs" (using git bash)

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I have 29 git commits of my project all in one and only master branch. Now there are bugs in the project and we are unable to solve the errors so we want to get exactly code what was at commit 22 but don't want to lose the commit 23-29 logs because my team is working on them (they are working using `git checkout <commit id>`)

Comment: You could revert commits 23-29. Then your code would be just like commit 22 without removing any commits. But I don't know what "they are working using git checkout" means. You mean everyone is in detached HEAD mode? That's not a good use of Git at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$ git restore -s head~7 -SW`

`-s` means source;
`-s head~7` means to restore from the source - the 7th previous commit;
`S` means to restore to the Staging area;
`W` means to restore to the Working tree.

All the commits (log) are kept.